# How to sum all cells that contains only time in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Some cells contains time and some of them '#VALUE!', '######' and just text.
I want to sum all cells that contains only time.

Meanwhile I wrote `=SUMIF(D13:D43,"<>#VALUE!")`, but it works only if the cell contains '#VALUE!'

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your range is from D2:D8, use the following array formula.

```
=SUM(IF(ISERROR(D2:D8),"",D2:D8))
```

To make an array formula press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER when done writing, instead of just ENTER>